# Git bash: whereis command not found

Tags: terminal, git-bash

I am using git bash on a windows machine. Everything works normally except for the `whereis` command. The terminal tells me the command is not found:

```
$ whereis grep
bash: whereis: command not found
```

I have already tried adding `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin` to my PATH.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: I don't believe git bash ships with `whereis`. It does have [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) or you can use Windows' [`where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html).

Comment: OK that would explain it. thx

Answer (score 4):

## Use the `where` in Windows

Utilized the command `whereis` in Linux is equals that command `where` , provided for  the Windows  kit for Windows 98, and is included by default in Server 2003, Vista, and newer versions :

```
$ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Users\MyUser\scoop\shims\git.exe
```

#### More information

- [Equivalent whereis in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis)
- [where.html](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

### Add the .exe in gitbash for Windows

While you want an executable of the  type `.exe` in gitbash you should be add in the follow path relation :

```
 C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\<EXE>.exe
```

*Or where there is ubication the folder `git` but always should be add in `mingw64\bin\`.*

### Install `whereis` in Windows

- You must download the following file:[whereis.zip](http://www.flounder.com/whereis.htm)
- Once unzipped, you should copy the `whereis.exe` file that is in :

  ```
  mvp_tips/whereis/Debug/
  ```
- And copy it in :

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\
  ```
- If all went well, close all the `GitBash` tabs and reopen one of them and enter :

  ```
  $ whereis whereis
  C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\whereis.exe #And what should come out if everything is correct:
  ```

#### Script for download and installation

**Run the `Git Bash` as `Run As Administrator`**

```
#!/bin/bash
wget www.flounder.com/whereis.zip
unzip whereis.zip
cd mvp_tips/whereis/Debug/
cp whereis.exe 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\'
source ~/.bashrc
whereis whereis
```